# How to make a json call with objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, xcode

I am implementing a calling with json with swift but I need this with Objective C . Can any one help me to convert this code to Objective C. It belongs to a project which it can convert currencies . I really appreciate any kinds of help. my problem is that how to do json calling with objective C . I tried some of swift to objective C converter but none of them works fine. Thats why I asked my question here,

```
   let url = URL(string: "https://something")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in            
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        for (key, value) in rates
                        {
                            self.myCurrency.append((key as! String))
                            self.myValues.append((value as? Double)!)                              
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }                    
            }                
        }
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        //myPicker.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        self.pickerView.selectRow(20, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
    task.resume()        
}
```

Comment: This is not a free code writing service, you are supposed to put in an effort yourself and write some code that we can help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest that you look through some previous similar posts and use them to guide you to your answer. The Objective-C largely follows the same pattern as you used for your Swift example.

I haven't tested this, but your code would end up looking something like the below.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:/something"];
NSURLSessionDataTask * task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if ((error) || (!data)) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    } else {
        NSError *err = nil;
        NSDictionary *json;
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
        if (json != nil && err == nil) {
            [json enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                [myCurrency addObject:key];
                [myValues addObject:obj];
            }];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
                [self.pickerView selectRow:20 inComponent:0 animated:false];

           });
        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. you did a lot for helping me during understanding how it will looks with objective C . Thank you very much